# Cannot install display drivers for ATI Radeon HD 4850 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Here are the specs:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- ATI Radeon HD 4850

Here's the antefact:

I was messing around with drivers trying to enable OpenCL. I might have involuntarily installed Catalyst 11.1 before sweeping the old drivers first. The thing quickly got out of hand resulting in me going on a [driver sweeping rampage](http://www.guru3d.com/category/driversweeper/), uninstalling then wiping the ATI drivers from my machine.

Problem:

The machine went into VGA adapter mode (it doesn't even see that it's a ATI card any more because there's no drivers), and **if I try to reinstall Catalyst the 'display driver' component no longer shows up any more** during the install process as it used to. I'm able to choose to install all sorts of other things but not the display drivers.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: In Device Manager, did you find the errant video adapter? You may be able to coerce Windows Updates to help you out with it there.

Comment: man, thanks! I was able to detach the device then do a scan for hardware changes and it went back to the way it was. I am back to square one (no OpenCL), but at least not in VGA mode. If you post your suggestion below I'll mark as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this - turns out my iMac mounts a **MOBILITY** card but Apple sells it as the standard HD 4850. I was trying to install drivers for the non-mobility version of the card.